# Get first part of string up to some string, that may or may not be in it

Tags: regex

I've got the following strings:

```
Showname  
Showname - with hyphen  
Showname - Season 4
```

What I want is:

```
Showname     
Showname - with hyphen
Showname
```

What I've come up with so far is:

```
/(.*)( - season /d/d?)/i
```

But that requires `- season ??` to be in the string, which is not always the case...

Any help would be really appreciated!

Cheers,
Roy

Comment: I'm confused about your question.  Are you looking to get rid of all characters after the hyphen, or just those that say "season ??"?

Comment: Just those that say "season ??" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basically, you want to strip off the season?

do a regex replace on

```
/ - season \d+$/i
```

and replace it with an empty string.

if the season isn't in there, nothing will get replaced and the original string will be returned.

Comment: Gah! Thanks! Never thought about that! Your the best ;)